# Rule Based String Manipulation II

Tags: string-manipulation

Thank you all for your suggestions for my previous question - very helpful indeed.  Here is a related but slightly different problem and I'd be grateful for input.

I have a series of strings that end with a space followed by 2, 3, or 4 capital letters:

```
 {A Big Cheese ABC}
 {Does Nothing DN}
 {for My Dental Health FMDH}
 {Insurance (IN) INS}
```

I'd like to split the strings to get:

```
 {A Big Cheese, ABC}
 {Does Nothing, DN}
 {for My Dental Health, FMDH}
 {Insurance (IN), INS}
```

This would seem to require a different Replace rule, as the all-caps segment of the strings are now of different lengths; the rule would also need to ignore consecutive caps when not at the end of the string, as in the fourth.  Again thanks in advance for ideas.

Comment: `StringSplit[#, 
  " " ~~ b : CharacterRange["A", "Z"] .. ~~ EndOfString :> b] &`

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a method that works for all cases including when the last word is not capitalized using `RegularExpression`**

```
data = {"A Big Cheese ABC", "A Big Cheese abc", "Does Nothing DN", 
"for My Dental Health FMDH", "Insurance (IN) INS"};

StringSplit[#, b__ ~~ " " ~~ patt : (RegularExpression["[A-Z]+"] ~~ EndOfString) :> 
Sequence[b, patt]] & /@ data

(* {{"A Big Cheese", "ABC"}, {"A Big Cheese abc"}, {"Does Nothing", 
"DN"}, {"for My Dental Health", "FMDH"}, {"Insurance (IN)", "INS"}} *)
```